# How to calculate weighted mean without numpy (or any package)

Tags: python

I'm try to reduce the dependency on packages and finds solutions to some statistical questions on mean, median, mode and weighted mean.

So basically I have two arrays, let us call them A and B with N elements. What will be the weighted mean of elements in B.

Here I do not want to use def weightedMean either. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I somehow know this one from https://www.hackerrank.com

Comment: Please post your existing code.

Comment: `sum(x * w for w, x in zip(A, B)) / sum(A)`?

Comment: What format are your weights in?

Comment: ... why do you *not* want to use a function? These specification seem rather arbitrary.

Comment: The question is sooo poorly formulated... For example, you say you have two arrays A and B but you do not specify how they are related. I understand if you do not want to introduce dependency on `numpy` but not even `def weightedMean()`...? Why??? It is so clear that you did not make any effort to understand the problem or attempt to solve it.

Comment: What part of the formula for [weighted mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Mathematical_definition) don't you understand (or know how to implement)?

Comment: I am trying to look for alternative solutions, hence not willing to use numpy.

Comment: @Adi219 my weights are integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def mul(tup):
    return tup[0]*tup[1]

A=[10, 40, 30, 50, 20]
B=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(round( sum(map(mul,zip(A,B)))/sum(B),1))
```

or

```
print(round( sum(map(lambda x: x[0]*x[1],zip(A,B)))/sum(B),1))
```

Which is essentially an inlined "function"

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/s10-weighted-mean/problem

Comment: I like `sum(x * w for w, x in zip(A, B)) / sum(A)` of @Graipher even better- less clunky then either of mine.

Comment: Sorry if this is very basic, but why do I get the weighted mean divided by 10 for this solution?

Comment: @guda - `A` numbers, `B` weights - thats probably the cause. If you use A as weights and B as numbers its 1/10 if you look at the numbers - just replace `sum(B)` with `sum(A)` if you have them the other way round

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done without using a function definition.

Try this:

```
wMean = 0
for i in range(N): ## Loop through all the weights
    wMean += (A[i] * B[i]) ## Multiply the weights by the result
wMean /= sum(A) ## Divide the sum to get the Weighted Mean
```

Of course, you could also define a function which multiplies two given numbers, and `map()` the `list`s using this function, but you've stated that you don't wish to use any functions.

Answer (score -1):

Building off of Adi219, when A is not in decimal form:

```
A=[10, 40, 30, 50, 20]
B=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

sumA = sum(A)
lenghtOfB = len(B)
wMean = 0
for i in range(lenghtOfB):
    wMean += (A[i]/sumA * B[i]) 

print('the weighed mean is: {}'.format(wMean))
```